# 03’ Dodge Durango brake light, fuse, and dash light issues

Tags: electrical, dodge, lights, fuse, durango

I have an 03 Dodge Durango. The driver side break light is out along with the taillights and dash lights.  I have replaced the fuse and the bulb socket as well as the bulb itself in the brake light it works for a short period of time then it shorts out the fuse and I only have one brake light working.  The dash lights taillights and one brake light out, what do I do?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The only thing which causes fuses to burn out is having too much amperage going through the wire, which means you have a short somewhere in your wiring. You're going to have to trace the wires using a multimeter to test them to see where the issue is at.

Comment: If you have a trailer hitch I would start  by checking the trailer harness.